# How to add class for per string after comma?

Tags: jquery

I tried to get the color of variable of woocommerce and meet the problem, I want to add html tag for each string after comma.

The code:

```
<p class="color">white, green</p>
```

I want to add html tag for each string as bellow:

```
<p class="color">white</p>
<p class="color">Green</p>
```

Comment: So there is a div with all colors, and you want to separate them in to different strings and remove the one containing all colors?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you could use a combination of `replaceWith()`, to overwrite the original `p` element, and `map()` to build multiple `p` elements from the comma separated list of colour names in the text of the original element, something like this:

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).text().split(',').map(function(t) {
    return `<p class="color">${t.trim()}</p>`;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="color">white, green</p>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped - this also goes for all your previous questions.